# Find dimension of space X

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given space $X$ that consists of matrices $V \in R^{n^2}$ such that $\forall k\in \mathbb{N} \sum_{i+j=k}v_{ij} = 1$. I need to find dimension of $X$.

Seems like for even $n$ such matrices are doubly symmetric. Any hints?

Comment: Is X a vector subspace of $R^{n^2}$?

Comment: $X$ is not a vector subspace. In what sense are you asking for its dimension?

Comment: @ReiHenigman yes, X is vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^{n x n}}$

Comment: Try and think of the axioms of a vector space to see if it's a subspace. Is it closed under multiplication by a scalar? @user1337157